# try catch until success java

Tags: java, selenium, try-catch

I get Stale Element Reference Exception.If I can single click. 
I want to click on element until or 5 times find the object.

How can I have try catch block loop until click or element found?
I want it to attempt to click on element for 5 times before failing it.
I use below code but not working.

Click Method:

```
public void click1(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, String name) {    
    int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 5) {
        try {
            element.click();
            Add_Log.info("Successfully clicked on  " + name);
            Reporter.log("Successfully clicked on " + name);
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
                Add_Log.info("Successfully clicked on  " + name);
                Reporter.log("Successfully clicked on " + name);
                break;
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                Add_Log.info("Not able to click " + name);
                Reporter.log("Not able to click " + name);
                TestResultStatus.Testfail = true;
                Assert.fail();
            }
        }
        attempts++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So... you want to do something in a loop until a condition is met?  Have you tried writing a loop?  What specifically is "not working" in your code?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually as easy as changing the loop condition from `attempts < 5` to `true` and removing the `attempts++;` line. At least that's what I understood from your question. If that's not what you're looking for, try rephrasing the question more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

I would write it more like the below. You attempt to do a normal click 5 times with a brief pause between attempts. If an exception is thrown, it's eaten and another attempt is made. If none of those 5 are successful, you make a single attempt to click on it using JS. If that fails, then log failures, etc.

```
public void click1(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, String name) {    
    int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 5) {
        try {
            element.click();
            Add_Log.info("Successfully clicked on " + name);
            Reporter.log("Successfully clicked on " + name);
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        attempts++;
        Thread.Sleep(500); // brief pause between attempts
    }

    try {
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
        Add_Log.info("Successfully clicked on " + name);
        Reporter.log("Successfully clicked on " + name);
        return;
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        Add_Log.info("Not able to click " + name);
        Reporter.log("Not able to click " + name);
        TestResultStatus.Testfail = true;
        Assert.fail("Not able to click " + name);
    }
}
```

NOTE: You probably would be better off waiting for the element to be clickable before attempting to click it. That would probably remedy most of your issues. You still may have an issue with some dialog/banner/spinner overlapping the element that you would need to deal with though... and you could deal with that with the 5 attempted clicks, etc.